# Import .txt into existing excel into new worksheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openxlsx

Im am completely stuck with the little project i am working on.
I am importing data from .txt files once a month, into an existing excel. Everytime i do this, i want to create a new worksheet in the excel and add the data into it, without changing anything in the other worksheets. My approach looks something like this.

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import os


now = date.today()
last_month = now.month-1 if now.month > 1 else 12
last_year = now.year - 1

if last_month != 1:
filename = "0" + str(last_month) + "." + str(now.year) + ".txt"

else:
    filename = "12" + "." + str(last_year) + ".txt"

print(filename)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("Ausgabenliste.xlsx", engine='openpyxl')


if os.path.exists("Ausgabenliste.xlsx"):
    book = openpyxl.load_workbook("Ausgabenliste.xlsx")
    writer.book = book
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=" ")
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=filename)
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

I always get the following error message:
[image]

Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This adds a new worksheet to an existing XLSX:

```
# Load existing 
book = load_workbook('x.xlsx')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('x.xlsx', engine = 'openpyxl')
# Starting with the existing worksheets
writer.book = book
# Adding a new worksheet
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='gtomer')
writer.save()
```

Comment: As far as i found on this forum xlsxwriter can not append, thats why i used openxlsx.